# Vuetify Rules Typescript with reference to Data() values

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

ie

```
data() { 
  return { 
    bar: false 

    rules: { 
      foo: (value) => {
         if (this.bar) {}
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Code works.

How do we get typescript to understand this?

If this is a "bad pattern" please be specific / suggest alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly suggest you use [vue-class-components](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) if you're looking for easy TypeScript support.

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
  bar: boolean = false;

  mounted () {
    this.bar = "test" // won't work because this.bar is a boolean
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I thought class components were being deprecated: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/class-components-in-vue-are-no-longer-happening

Comment: As far as I've understood it, it's for the upcoming Vue3 Release. In Vue2 it works perfectly as of now.